# Maven won't run at all

Tags: java, maven-3

My Environment variables are

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2
M3_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4
M3 = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4
MAVEN_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4
MAVEN_OPTS = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4
```

My PATH Vars are

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin
C:\Windows\System32
```

I ran java -verison and the output was

```
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

But when I run mvn --version

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Program
```

Can someone please tell me why maven won't run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the `MAVEN_OPTS` to `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4`. Leave it empty.

This environment variable is meant to pass additional command line options to the JVM when it is running maven.